# Unable to change php version of wordpress docker image

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, version

My wordpress container has php version 7.3 but my **docker-compose**  file looks like this

```
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: wordpress:php8.1-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
```

No metter what I do always is 7.3. Its strange that where I start **docker compose up**   system pull two images

1. wordpress php7.3-fpm
2. wordpress php8.1-fpm

When I inspect my wordpress container it says that I am using php8.1-fpm but when I print php version inside of container php version is 7.3?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Did you also tell Apache to use the new version of PHP

Comment: It`s  on nginx, can you help me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
docker container stop wordpress
docker container rm wordpress
```

After add new php

```
docker container start wordpress
```

You must remove old container because it include version 7.3, then must run container with 8.1 version